# Are there any Java based libraries that provide game mapping features?

Tags: java, maps

I'm working on a Java web based game in my spare time (springMVC / JSPs etc), and I'm wondering what are my options for dealing with the "game world" or mapping element.

My game will be 2d / text based, so I have no need for any OpenGL / Flash etc.

My initial idea was to use Google maps and provide a custom overlay, but I want to know if there are any alternatives?

For example, if I create a 2d map with all my zones, are there any libraries that will help me plot players, work out distances and so forth?

Regards

Comment: is this a graphics questions? not sure what you're really looking for.

Comment: Dont care about graphics, I'm making a simple Java web based game (using JSP / JSTL etc). I'm looking for a library or something I can use to handle maps, i.e., where players are on a map, where towns are, where people can travel to etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but heres a 2d map editor built in java available for free http://www.mapeditor.org/

Comment: Slick2d supports the map editor I just linked.